# Should I create an abstract runnable? I've 4 sub-classes which perform similar work but only 3 of them have identical constructors

Tags: java, object-oriented, classes, inheritance

I've added the code for an abstract thread class and 2 sub-classes. The structure and job of the threads (sub-classes) is identical except one difference: `ONE` of the sub-classes, `RefreshData` does not need the client parameter. I've overloaded the constructor in the sub-class but I'm not sure if the abstraction makes sense anymore. Moreover, can I do something to ensure that `RefreshData` doesn't use the inherited `client` parameter accidentally and ends up getting an NPE.

```
    public abstract class BackgroundTask implements Runnable {

      protected final Manager manager;
      protected final Client client;
      private long msSyncInterval;
      private boolean shutdown; // has a setter 

    public BackgroundTask(final Manager manager, final long msSyncInterval) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.client = null;
        this.msSyncInterval = msSyncInterval;
        this.shutdown = shutdown;
    }

    public BackgroundTask(final Manager manager, final Client client, final long msSyncInterval) {
        this.manager = manager;
        this.client = client;
        this.msSyncInterval = msSyncInterval;
        this.shutdown = shutdown;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!shutdown) {
            executeTask();

            // sleep for msSyncInterval
        }
    }

    abstract void executeTask();
}

public class ExchangeData extends BackgroundTask {

    public ExchangeData(final Manager manager, final Client client, final long msSyncInterval) {
        super(manager, client, msSyncInterval);
    }

    @Override
    void executeTask() {
        // Some work here
    }
}


public class RefreshData extends BackgroundTask {

    public RefreshThrottleLimits(final Manager manager, final long msSyncInterval) {
        super(throttleManager, msSyncInterval);
    }

    @Override
    void executeTask() {
        // Doesn't use the client
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better to implement the convenience constructors in terms of the other, more detailed one, like this:

```
public BackgroundTask(final Manager manager, final long msSyncInterval) {
    this(manager, null, msSyncInterval);
}
```

(Btw it seems you forgot the `boolean shutdown` parameter.)

The manager and the client fields are not used in the posted code.
If this is indeed what you have in your use case,
then I think these fields don't belong in the parent class.
Adding fields in the parent that itself doesn't need makes the code more complex:
if you hadn't added those fields, you wouldn't be asking now what to do with one unused field.

If the code you posted is not complete, and in fact the parent *is really using* those fields, then another option can be to use a dummy implementation of a client instead of a `null` value.

Finally, have you considered using composition instead of inheritance?
**This is actually the single most important question to evaluate every time before choosing to use inheritance.**
You could rename `BackgroundTask` to `BackgroundTaskRunner`,
and create a `BackgroundTask` interface with an `executeTask` method.

Of course, sometimes inheritance is the answer.
In this case I question your decision because of signs that seem to suggest otherwise:

- Inheritance is designed for "is a" relationships. Can you say that `ExchangeData` "is a" `BackgroundTask`? Maybe it's easier to from another angle: if you had to pick the one defining characteristic of `ExchangeData`, will it be that it's a `BackgroundTask`? Or will it be something else? It seems to me its main purpose is not really being a background task. It's main purpose is something else, and you just want to make it do its job in the background.
- *Inheritance is the complex idea that one class is a specialization of another class* ([Code Complete](http://www.cc2e.com/)) Here, this doesn't seem to be the case. Although you want to run `ExchangeData` in the background, it's certainly not a special case of `BackgroundTask`
- The idea of running stuff in the background is so common that there exist high-level utility classes for that [in the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/highlevel.html). Instead of using the low-level `Runnable`, you can probably benefit from using one of the high-level solutions, such as [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

All things considered, you know your problem domain the best,
so you are in the best position to decide whether composition or inheritance is the right design. But at the minimum, you should at least consider this alternative.

Comment: I'll consider using Executors, but I'd still like to understand this better.You see all the threads have to be run in background in the same format, sleep work and so on..I read the official documentation on abstract classes and it said, that you should consider using abstract classes if any one of these 3 conditions is true: 1) You want to share code among several closely related classes. 2) You expect that classes that extend your abstract class have many common methods or fields 3) You want to declare non-static or non-final fields.

Comment: And I'd certainly say yes for pt 2.

Comment: or else I'll have to copy the same run() method in all the classes.

Comment: I see you're referring to the [official guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html). That guide seems superficial compared to Code Complete, where I pulled my first 2 points above. I think this official guide is designed for beginners, and focuses on the distinction between interfaces and abstract classes, which is a narrow view, missing the bigger picture. Look for guides about inheritance versus composition, the latter is recommended when possible.

Comment: You can keep the `run()` method in the `BackgroundTaskRunner`, just like the `ExecutorService` does.

Answer (score 2):

You have field `shutdown` that you mutating in a multithreaded code, this field can be cached and might ignore you changing it. You can declare it as `volatile` to avoid this behavior.

```
private volatile boolean shutdown;
```

What makes your abstraction leaky is the fact that `BackgroundTask` is not abstract enough, that is, Manager and client shouldn't be there.

```
 public abstract class BackgroundTask implements Runnable {

   abstract void executeTask();
   private boolean shutdown;

   @Override
   public void run() {
    while (!shutdown) {
        executeTask();

        // sleep for msSyncInterval
    }
  }
 }
```

And now we can have an abstract class that does Task involving clients and managers

```
 abstract class AbstractManagerClientTask extends BackgroundTask { // not sure about the name
   protected final Manager manager;
   protected final Client client;
   .....
 }
```

ExchangeData is more specific than a `BackgroundTask`, it is a `AbstractManagerClientTask`

```
  class ExchangeData extends AbstractManagerClientTask{
   ...
  }
```

It's much easier now, `RefreshData` can extend `BackgroundTask` with its own Manager field

```
 public class RefreshData extends BackgroundTask {
  private final Manager manager;
  ....
 }
```